# Any change to the customized Django User Model is completely ignored in the Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin

I customized the User model by extending AbstractUser, not AbstractBaseUser, because I don't need to remove the username, I just need to authenticate users by email and I still want to use the authentication system that comes with Django. Therefore I just defined the email address as the username and I extended AbstractUser before any migration.

But the Admin doesn't recognize this and completely ignores what I specify in admin.py, except the register instruction. Here's the content of my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from .models import User as CustomUser
from .forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm
# from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# I obviously tried by extending UserAdmin too, no result
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser

    fields = ('email')
    # commenting or uncommenting the following doesn't change anything
    """
    list_display = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    exclude = ('first_name',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    """


admin.site.register(CustomUser, BaseUserAdmin)
```

I tried everything and nothing works. I can't add the email field in the Add User form, and I can't remove the first and last_name from http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/user/

It seems that the Django built-in Admin ignores any change made in any class extending AbstractUser

Obviously everything is correct in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

# this is necessary for the custom user model and must to be taken into account before any migration will occur. 
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifier for 
    authentication instead of username.
    Between the username field (email) and password, you must put all
    the required fields. extra_fields must contain all the optional 
    fields.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an Username")

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username, 
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            password=password
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

"""
This model behaves identically to the default user model, but you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises. This is the recommended behavior
"""

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    """
    The REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username'] must be present, otherwise the following error will arise:
        TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
    """
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def getEmailField(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py:

```
class UserChangeForm(auth_forms.UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(auth_forms.UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'


class UserCreationForm(auth_forms.UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(auth_forms.UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

Obviously I tried with several things in fields = 'whatever' but any and every change I try, is happily ignored, the Admin will always display the data and the forms in the same way as the default.

My views.py...........

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.template import RequestContext

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, "users/dashboard.html")

def register(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(
            request, "users/register.html",
            {"form": CustomUserCreationForm}
        )
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            # the form.cleaned_data must be used after calling 
            # the form.is_valid method. 
            # if(email_matches(form.cleaned_data["email"], form.cleaned_data["email2"])):
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(reverse("dashboard"))
            
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, "users/register.html", context)

def home_page(request):
    return render(request, "home_page.html")
```

I read somewhere that it is not possible to override anything from the AbstractUser class and to do this, I must extend the AbstractBaseUser class directly.

Is this also valid with the Admin forms? After all, I'm not overriding anything, I just trying to display the email address in the Admin Add User form.

But supposing I can't really customize anything coming from the AbstractUser. Why are things like that? This is not a today problem. I have been trying to understand this behavior for over a week now and neither the documentation nor the internet is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the wrong admin:

```
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending `admin.ModelAdmin` for `CustomUserAdmin`, you should do something like this-

```
class CustomUserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    ...
    ...
```

And then please correct your model registration line like this-

```
admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

P.S. Do not forget to uncomment the lines you have commented.

Comment: What's the explanation for using `BaseUserAdmin` instead of `admin.ModelAdmin`?  If there's no explanation, how is my answer different to yours? :D

Comment: @bdbd, The reason is the `password` field. When you use `BaseUserAdmin`, the `password` field would be treated as a hashed uneditable field. But in the case of `admin.ModelAdmin`, the `password` field would be treated as charfield with the hashed password value.

Comment: No, because the OP's `CustomUserAdmin` uses the same forms as `UserAdmin`/`BaseUserAdmin` so it will behave the same way. But yeah it would be better to use `UserAdmin` instead of how it is currently.

Comment: Super! Everything works correctly! I just would like to understand better what I had wrong.